# How to loop over part of a character string and make a new column

Tags: r, dataframe

I need to make dummies for all weaks from 2000-2020 and think of using a for loop. My data looks like this

```
df <- data.frame( Time = c("2000W01","2000W02", "2000W03", "2000W04"
                    ,"2001W01","2001W02", "2001W03", "2001W04",
                    "2002W01","2002W02", "2002W03", "2002W04"),
                   Total = c(rep(3,12)))

df
    Time Total
1  2000W01     3
2  2000W02     3
3  2000W03     3
4  2000W04     3
5  2001W01     3
6  2001W02     3
7  2001W03     3
8  2001W04     3
9  2002W01     3
10 2002W02     3
11 2002W03     3
12 2002W04     3
```

I want to make a dummy variable (0 or 1) depending on which week of the year it is

```
    df <- data.frame( Time = c("2000W01","2000W02", "2000W03", "2000W04"
                        ,"2001W01","2001W02", "2001W03", "2001W04",
                        "2002W01","2002W02", "2002W03", "2002W04"),
                       Total = c(rep(3,12)),
             spring = c(1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0),
             summer = c(0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0),
             autumn = c(0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0),
             winter = c(0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,1))




       Time Total spring summer autumn winter
1  2000W01     3      1      0      0      0
2  2000W02     3      0      1      0      0
3  2000W03     3      0      0      1      0
4  2000W04     3      0      0      0      1
5  2001W01     3      1      0      0      0
6  2001W02     3      0      1      0      0
7  2001W03     3      0      0      1      0
8  2001W04     3      0      0      0      1
9  2002W01     3      1      0      0      0
10 2002W02     3      0      1      0      0
11 2002W03     3      0      0      1      0
12 2002W04     3      0      0      0      1
```

How can I do this for a large dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `case_when` to assign seasons and cast the data to wide format.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  mutate(season = case_when(grepl('W01', Time) ~ 'spring', 
                            grepl('W02', Time) ~ 'summer', 
                            grepl('W03', Time) ~ 'autumn', 
                            grepl('W04', Time) ~ 'winter')) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = season, values_from = season, 
              values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

#   Time    Total spring summer autumn winter
#   <chr>   <dbl>  <int>  <int>  <int>  <int>
# 1 2000W01     3      1      0      0      0
# 2 2000W02     3      0      1      0      0
# 3 2000W03     3      0      0      1      0
# 4 2000W04     3      0      0      0      1
# 5 2001W01     3      1      0      0      0
# 6 2001W02     3      0      1      0      0
# 7 2001W03     3      0      0      1      0
# 8 2001W04     3      0      0      0      1
# 9 2002W01     3      1      0      0      0
#10 2002W02     3      0      1      0      0
#11 2002W03     3      0      0      1      0
#12 2002W04     3      0      0      0      1
```

Comment: What if I have 52 weeks and want W48-W08 (12 months) as winter and same for summer, autum and spring? Can I just use grepl("W01|W02|W03")  and so on?

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Or another option is to separate year and week information and then do something like `Week %in% c('W01', 'W02'...) ~ 'spring'`

Comment: is there a difference between "W01" and 'W01' ?

Comment: No..there is no difference.

Comment: I am trying to do the same with months, the code runs but I only get january. I don't want to make a new post but I can show my code. Its right here

Comment: df <- df %>%
   mutate(month = case_when( grepl('W1|W2|W3|W4|W5',      Time) ~ 'January', 
                             grepl('W6|W7|W8|W9',         Time) ~ 'February',
                          
                            
                             grepl('W40|W41|W42|W43|44',  Time) ~ 'October',
                             grepl('W45|W46|W47|W48',     Time) ~ 'November',
                             grepl('W49|W50|W51|W52|53',  Time) ~ 'December')) %>%
   pivot_wider(names_from = month, values_from = month, 
               values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)

Comment: I had to cut out months from january to october cause it couldn't fit in the comments

Comment: Do you have values as W01 or W1 ? Anyway, I think you need to use word boundary like this i.e `grepl('\\b(W1|W2|W3|W4|W5)\\b', Time)` because `W1` matches `W11` as well etc. Using word boundary (`\\w`) should help.

Comment: Thank you! I forgot something obvious and yes I do have "W01" to not confuse "grep". However, the season code gives me an error and wont compute. Error: Failed to create output due to bad names.
* Choose another strategy with `names_repair. I tried putting this to "minimal" but it doesnt work.

Comment: I am not sure what might be causing the error. It would be better if you ask it as a new question with relevant data to reproduce the error.

Comment: Sure I will make a new post if this last question does not solve my problem. I originally excluded some weeks and ran the code but decided to change the definition of spring so to last for more weeks and some of the weeks that were previously winter became spring like week 9 (sometimes winter sometimes spring). However, it is like R still remembers that initial definition of my seasons.. Like the variable "season" are defined in some hidden environment I dont know. I have included the \\b \\b

Answer (score 1):

You could use a look-up vector to get the specific naming and `pivot_wider`:

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)

lookup <- c("Spring", "Summer", "Autumn", "Winter")
names(lookup) <- 1:4
df %>%
    mutate(week = lookup[stringr::str_sub(Time, start = -1)],
           v = 1) %>%
    pivot_wider(id_cols = c(Time, Total), 
                names_from = week, 
                values_from = v,
                values_fill = 0)
```